# Is the Percussion Content Management System customizable (programmatically)?

Tags: content-management-system

Just wondering if anyone out there has recent experience programming in the Percussion CMS environment. Is it pretty "locked down", or when you find that the default admin settings won't facilitate achieving some type of functionality, can you get to the source code files and/or the database and really make it do what you want? Is there an API?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Percussion CMS (Percussion CM) provides Web Services / SOAP endpoints (http://goo.gl/NdDvi) that you can call to perform all functions that you would typically do through the provided user interface. In addition to Web Services, developers can create Java and JavaScript extensions that allow content items, content item fields, publish runtimes, and templates to be enhanced beyond the factory default (http://goo.gl/Rda5u).

Please read through the help web site, http://help.percussion.com/cmsystem/index, to fully understand how Percussion CMS operates as a decoupled content management system.

Also note that there is a Percussion CM1 that does not offer the same extensibility.